"EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink ''<path-to-pnpm>\pnpm.EXE" when trying to update pnpm
I'm using pnpm 9.12.3 and trying to update to the newest version by running the command: pnpm self-update, but I get the following error:

WARN  The target bin directory already contains an exe called pnpm, so removing 
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\pnpm\pnpm.EXE 
EPERM  EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 
'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\pnpm\pnpm.EXE'

There is an open github issue for the problem that has a lot of different things one can try. I've tried a lot of the suggestions on the github page by now, but the error message still persists and pnpm won't update.
The issue appears to be a kind of chicken and egg problem where pnpm tries to delete its own .exe file as part of the updating procedure,  but can't delete the .exe file as the program (pnpm) is already running and Windows can't delete the .exe files of running programs.
The newest version of pnpm is currently 9.14.4. So, does anyone out there have a working solution for how to update pnpm to the newest version?

Okay, so I eventually found a solution that worked for me, thanks to qiantum for posting the solution on GitHub. Basically what you need to do is rename pnpm.exe, then update pnpm, then remove the renamed pnpm.exe after the update succeeds. The pnpm.exe program is apparently not needed/located in the same directory after the update.
My pnpm.exe was located in 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\pnpm\pnpm.EXE'
Here are the steps: 
1. Make sure node.js already installed
2. Rename pnpm.exe to pnpm_.exe
3. Run the command: 'pnpm_ -g i pnpm'
4. Make sure file pnpm.cmd appeared
5. Delete pnpm_.exe
6. Done. now pnpm manages itself

